# How to enable RGB subpixel font anti-aliasing in KDE Plasma?

Tags: kde, fonts

I have installed Debian 11 with both Gnome and KDE and soon I noticed that all fonts looks uglier under KDE than under Gnome even when running the same application and having the same font settings.

So, I took and zoomed some screenshots and the difference seems to be in different anti-aliasing.

Note that under both Gnome and KDE, my font settings is the same:

- Hinting: Full
- Anti-aliasing: Subpixel RGB

From the screenshots it's obvious that when I run Konsole under Gnome, the fonts are rendered correctly with the subpixel RGB AA, but when I run the same Konsole under KDE Plasma, the AA looks like to be grayscale only.

My question is: Does anyone also noticed that and is it possible to fix it somehow or is it some bug in KDE Plasma?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think I've found where is the issue. The user config file, which controls the font rendering under KDE, is `~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf` and it seems the KDE System Settings fails to set the property `rgba` which controls the RGB subpixel anti-aliasing. I guess it's a bug in KDE Plasma System Settings?

As a solution I used an utility **qt5ct**, which has an option to generate the `fonts.conf` file. But I guess you can just manually modify the file as well to add the `rgba` property.

Now, with the following `fonts.conf`, the fonts look like having the same RGB subpixel rendering under KDE like they have under Gnome.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
    <match target="font">
        <edit name="antialias" mode="assign">
            <bool>true</bool>
        </edit>
        <edit name="hinting" mode="assign">
            <bool>true</bool>
        </edit>
        <edit name="hintstyle" mode="assign">
            <const>hintfull</const>
        </edit>
        <edit name="rgba" mode="assign">
            <const>rgb</const>
        </edit>
        <edit name="autohint" mode="assign">
            <bool>false</bool>
        </edit>
        <edit name="lcdfilter" mode="assign">
            <const>lcddefault</const>
        </edit>
        <edit name="dpi" mode="assign">
            <double>102</double>
        </edit>
    </match>
</fontconfig>
```

[image]